I am getting Content-Security-Policy warnings on chrome, but they go away if I hard refresh the page
I maintain a large web app, containing lots of css and javascript.
I recently set a Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header:
script-src 'nonce-0WcV5zOA5A7iZNNopffdzl/B3cbrn3Voq6lg8PJDvqo='; style-src 'nonce-0WcV5zOA5A7iZNNopffdzl/B3cbrn3Voq6lg8PJDvqo='; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; report-uri /error/cspreport;

All my script and css now includes an appropriate nonce, but I am still getting warnings from Chrome that the policy has been violated.
After getting the warning, if I Ctrl-F5 (hard refresh) the chrome page, the warnings go away.
Can anyone explain why this might be?
